# gst-launch return value

Tags: error-handling, return-value, gstreamer, gst-launch

What will be the return value of gst-launch application? Will it return '0' on success and non-negative number (ERROR CODE) on failure? Where can I fild list of all possible error codes of gst-launch.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux the exit status code of last command is stored in variable `$?`. Typically it's `0` for success and non-zero for failure.

```
gst-launch v4l2src num-buffers=1 ! xvimagesink
echo $?
```

shows

```
0
```

while something erroneous like

```
gst-launch junk
echo $?
```

shows

```
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, all ok is 0, not able to make sense of the pipeline is 1 (like already stated), and not being able to start or stop the pipeline is -1, and that's it. (gst-launch is meant as a prototyping-tool, and for real use of it, you need to use code, hence the not very comprehensive error-codes.)